# Get ADFS SAML 2.0 Assertion Response from command line using curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I would to know WINDOWS Server ADFS really exposes an API to post SAML request en get saml assertion response.

When I enter this in my browser : `https://<myfqdn>/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx`

I’m presented with a site selection page, as shown in the following image **[image: SAML response]** .
Then I choose AWS, and get to the authentication page to provide my AD credentials, after what I get to AWS console page.
It's a `POST` request and If activate my **Google Chrome Developer Tools** for example, I can see the from headers

However I'm trying to reproduce the same from my Linux command line using curl but It's not working.

This is what I'm trying :

```
$api_body="{\"service\": \"aws\", \"email\": \"myemail\", \"password\": \"mypass\"}"
$SAML_IDP_ASSERTION_URL=https://<myfqdn>/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx
$curl -sD -  -X POST "$SAML_IDP_ASSERTION_URL" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$api_body"
```

This gives me the following header :

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Content-Length: 12844
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> Expires: -1
>
> Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>
> x-frame-options: DENY
>
> Date: Fri, 22 Mar 2019 10:25:13 GMT

Followed by the site html content in my terminal including javascript and others. I don't get or see any json data back, nor SAML Response.

Do you guys have an idea of what's the right command/request to get SAML Response from command line?

Comment: Every SAMLv2 exposes an endpoint which you can use to get a SAMLResponse. This endpoint is called 'SingleSignOn URL'. Typically different 'protocol bindings' are  provided for the 'SSO endpoint' e.g. 'HTTP REDIRECT' and 'HTTP POST' binding.
However you only get a SAMLResponse when the IdP successfully verifies the SAML AuthnRequest and whe you are authenticated with the IdP. If the latter is not the case the IdP has to prompt you for authentication.

Comment: I followed this documentation : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-implement-federated-api-and-cli-access-using-saml-2-0-and-ad-fs/ and succeeded to get my SAML Response  using python, but not exactly the same way I was trying with curl in bash. However I'll try to implement the bash version from there.